# In the wso2 api manager, what populates {endpoint.URLs.http} in the Environment.jsx file?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

```
{endpoint.URLs.http !== null && (
                                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                                <TextField
                                                    defaultValue={endpoint.URLs.http}
                                                    id='bootstrap-input'
                                                    InputProps={{
                                                        disableUnderline: true,
                                                        readOnly: true,
                                                        classes: {
                                                            root: classes.bootstrapRoot,
                                                            input: classes.bootstrapInput,
                                                        },
                                                    }}
```

These text fields display the http and https gateway urls. How does `endpoint.URLs.http` and `endpoint.URLs.https` get it's vales(the gateway urls).

Answer (score 1):

For OpenAPI v3, it comes under the servers and in the backend the following methods add those values to the OpenAPI definition.

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/definitions/OAS3Parser.java#L1201

Answer (score 1):

The `Gateway urls` are generated in this method - [1] based on the type of the APIs.

**Edit**:

To be precise, the context and version is appended in this line in default behavior - [2].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/v1/mappings/APIMappingUtil.java#L753

[2] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/v1/mappings/APIMappingUtil.java#L797

Comment: What about the getgatewayEndpoing function in the APIUtil.java file ? https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/utils/APIUtil.java#2352

Comment: and if i want to make a change to the gateway urls generated for a specific kind of apis where should i make the changes. I'm a bit confused, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I believe you are referring to the method -`getGatewayendpoint(String transports)`. This method is used to retrieve the gateway URLs defined in `api-manager.xml`

Comment: Have you checked this [method](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/v1/mappings/APIMappingUtil.java#L773-L777). Here we have similar logic in constructing GW url for web socket APIs and HTTP

Comment: Hi, in the APIMappingUtil.java function what is the purpose of the customGatewayUrl attribute ?

Comment: Hi @AkshithaDalpethado, custom gateway URLs can be defined for gateway per tenant. This attribute is used in that flow. You can get more information from this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/customizations/customize-the-api-store-and-gateway-urls-for-tenants/#setup-custom-domain-mapping-in-the-registry).

Comment: Thanks @vithursa. My project is about getting aws apis to the wso2 dev portal. For these apis i need to stop the generation of gateway urls. ex `(https://localhost:8243/<context>/version` and instead i want  `host url` of the api displayed in the dev portal gateway urls. ex `(ern7ceaofh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)`. How do I achieve this? Im not sure whether the generated gateway urls come under one variable.

Comment: I assume, you are creating an API in publisher and set AWS endpoint as endpoint URL. Is this understanding correct? If so, is there any attribute you used to differentiate AWS apis in API object. For instance, do you set a different endpoint_type as done [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1/src/main/resources/publisher-api.yaml#L7878) or type attribute in API? Also, where do you store the hostname attribute?

Comment: Actually i introduced a new command to the apictl which will get the swagger from aws and initializes a  wso2 api project using that swagger. for now to recognize an aws api i'll be using the `advertiseOnly` property. for ex if advertise only is set to true it will be recognized as an aws api. And the the host url will be in the swagger.yaml file after initializing the wso2 project.

Comment: When creating the API, you can parse the swagger, get the relevant host name and store it as an attribute against the API. You can check the `advertiseOnly` property before appending the API context to the URL (in the method I pointed above) and if it is `true` you can set the `host_url` as endpoint.